# Exception creating bean of X under form name X

Tags: struts

I developed a small project a while back using Struts 1.3. Last time I tested it it ran perfectly. Now, I'm trying to run it again (the exact same code) but I get the following problem:

`javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception creating bean of class test.form.SendFileForm under form name SendFileForm`

I tried to run it both on Tomcat 6 and Tomcat 7 but no luck.

This is the SendFileForm class.

```
public class SendFileForm extends ActionForm{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(SendFileForm.class);

private FormFile uploadFile;

@Override
public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
    log.info("=> SendFileForm - validate - enter");
    log.info("=< SendFileForm - validate - exit");
    return super.validate(mapping, request);
}   
public FormFile getUploadFile() {
    return uploadFile;
}

public void setUploadFile(FormFile uploadFile) {
    this.uploadFile = uploadFile;
}

}
```

I have no idea why this problem appears but if you need more details regarding other classes please comment and I'll provide them.

**Note 1:** Another answer stated that it is possible to have something like `SendFileForm SendFileForm = new SendFileForm()` which is obviously wrong. I don;t have anything like that.